# Customize logs from filebeat in the Lostash's beats.config

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat

I am using ELK with filebeat. I am sending logs from filebeat to Logstash and from there to Elastic and visualizing in Kibana. 
I am pasting the json result that is displayed in kibana's log result which is as below:

```
    {
  "_index": "filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.30",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2018-10-30T09:15:31.697Z",
    "fields": {
      "server": "server1"
    },
    "prospector": {
      "type": "log"
    },
    "host": {
      "name": "kushmathapa"
    },
    "message": "{ \"datetime\": \"2018-10-23T18:04:00.811660Z\", \"level\": \"ERROR\", \"message\": \"No response from remote. Handshake timed out or transport failure detector triggered.\" }",
    "source": "C:\\logs\\batch-portal\\error.json",
    "input": {
      "type": "log"
    },
    "beat": {
      "name": "kushmathapa",
      "hostname": "kushmathapa",
      "version": "6.4.2"
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "tags": [
      "lighthouse1",
      "controller",
      "trt"
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2018-10-30T09:15:31.697Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

I want this to show as

```
    {
  "_index": "filebeat-6.4.2-2018.10.30",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2018-10-30T09:15:31.697Z",
    "fields": {
      "server": "server1"
    },
    "prospector": {
      "type": "log"
    },
    "host": {
      "name": "kushmathapa"
    },
    "datetime": 2018-10-23T18:04:00.811660Z,
    "log_level": ERROR,
    "message": "{ \"No response from remote. Handshake timed out or transport failure detector triggered.\" }",
    "source": "C:\\logs\\batch-portal\\error.json",
    "input": {
      "type": "log"
    },
    "beat": {
      "name": "kushmathapa",
      "hostname": "kushmathapa",
      "version": "6.4.2"
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "tags": [
      "lighthouse1",
      "controller",
      "trt"
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2018-10-30T09:15:31.697Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

My beats.config looks like this right now

```
  input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" 
  } stdout {
    codec => rubydebug { metadata => true }
  }
}
```

I have applied filters but i seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the config file which looks something like this.
 In the grok filter, add the format of your log that you want to ingest to your elasticsearch(for example refer the mentioned config).

```
input {
beats {
port => 5044
id => "my_plugin_id"
tags => ["logs"]
type => "abc"
}
}
filter {
if [type] == "abc" {
 mutate {
    gsub => [ "message", "\r", "" ]
}

    grok {
        break_on_match => true
                match => {
                         "message" => [
                         "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}"
                         ]
                  }
                  overwrite => [ "message" ]
    }

    grok {
        break_on_match => true
                match => {
                         "message" => [
                          "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:log_level}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}"
                         ]
                  }
                  overwrite => [ "message" ]
    }

date {
   match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
} 
}
}
output {
if [type] == "abc" {
elasticsearch { 
hosts => ["ip of elasticsearch:port_number of elasticsearch"]
index => "logfiles"
} 
}
else {
elasticsearch { 
hosts => ["ip of elasticsearch:port_number of elasticsearch"]
index => "task_log"
} 
}
stdout {
codec => rubydebug { metadata => true }
}
}
```

Comment: Since message is in json(updates in the question), the grok filter does not work as the message is in json format

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869886/sending-json-format-log-to-kibana-using-filebeat-logstash-and-elasticsearch I guess you will get an idea regarding your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Logstash needs to know that the `message` field you are receiving is in JSON format. You can use the `json` filter here and get almost all of what you're looking for out of the box:

```
filter {
    json {
        target => "message"
    }
}
```

You can use mutation or add/remove fields to rename things like `level` to `log.level` and `datetime` to `@datetime` if those names are necessary.